# Not able to connect to mysql database using command line in windows 8

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to my database I am using following command

```
mysql> use ideconnect -u root -p   -h localhost;
```

There is no password given in my computer but it still shows

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ideconnec
t'
```

any idea what should I do

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you use mysql command to login as a given user first: `mysql -u root -p ideconnect`? USE command is used just to change the database.

Comment: @Harsh okay let me try

Comment: @Harsh when I do that it give me error in my sql syntax

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to login and connect to your specific database in one command use following command**

mysql -u root -p ideconnect

**if you want to login only ** 
mysql -u root -p

**after login change database**

use ideconnect

i hope this answers;
thanks
Muhammad Amir

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u root -p' at line 1`

Comment: whats ur mysql version

Comment: did u try only login in step 1

Comment: and use database in step 2

Comment: is ur root user have a password ?

Comment: if there is no password for your root user then do not use -p

Comment: yes there is no password sorry for late reply I am gong to check now

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```